# Send POST data to another site Ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post

I have this script that's "supposed" to send SVG/SVG Layer data to R* Social club for automatic emblem uploading, but it doesn't seem to work, am I missing something?

Original Script [Flashback GTA's Emblem Helper](https://pastebin.com/XybUZYPB)

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest;
request.open("POST","/emblems/save",!0),request.onreadystatechange=function()
{
if(request.readyState==XMLHttpRequest.DONE)
{
var a=JSON.parse(request.responseText);
200==a.Status?window.location.href="https://socialclub.rockstargames.com/emblems/edit/%22+a.EmblemId:a.Message?alert(a.Message):alert(a.Error.Message)%7D%7D,request.setRequestHeader(%22Content-Type%22,%22application/json%22),request.setRequestHeader(%22__RequestVerificationToken%22,document.getElementsByName(%22__RequestVerificationToken%22)[0].value),request.setRequestHeader(%22X-Requested-With%22,%22XMLHttpRequest%22),request.send(JSON.stringify(%7B%22crewId%22:%220%22,%22emblemId%22:%22%22,%22parentId%22:%22%22,%22svgData%22:svgData,%22layerData": layerData,"hash":document.getElementById("editorField-hash").value}));
```

The above code (along with its related hashes) are output when the emblem is generated.  From what it seems to me (idk much about JS) is that its a post request trying to send the post data, but it seems, idk, incomplete?  Maybe posting the svg data would work via ajax?  I'd just like to upload better emblems.

I'd like to somehow send the data directly to the external site, either using POST or by somehow forcing console commands vs copy/pasting it in by hand.